# how to execute ipconfig using createprocess() in vc++ with visible command prompt?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to implement a method that executes command "ipconfig" in command prompt and show that output in command prompt.

currently i am using

```
STARTUPINFO StartUpInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcInformation;

memset(&StartUpInfo, 0, sizeof(StartUpInfo) );
memset(&ProcInformation, 0, sizeof(ProcInformation) );

StartUpInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
StartUpInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;

CreateProcess(csCMDExeFullPath_EP, csCommanddLineParams_EP.GetBuffer
     ( csCommanddLineParams_EP.GetLength() + ONE), NULL, 
     NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL,&StartUpInfo, &ProcInformation );

//Wait for the executing process to complete
WaitForSingleObject(ProcInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);
GetExitCodeProcess(ProcInformation.hProcess, &dwExecuteProcess_ExecExitCode_EP );

csCommanddLineParams_EP.ReleaseBuffer();

//Close handle of the process
CloseHandle(ProcInformation.hProcess);

//Close handle of the threads
CloseHandle(ProcInformation.hThread);`
```

My current code is working fine but command prompt visible and disappears in seconds.
But my requirement is to show output in cmd.

Can any one help me on this.

Comment: What are you trying to use `ipconfig` to accomplish? Chances are pretty good that you can write code to do that job more directly without using ipconfig.

Comment: It is not not only ipconfig and some more commands which are being read by program from config file.

Comment: I generally agree with Jerry's comment. But if `ipconfig` is your only option you might start `cmd.exe /K ipconfig.exe`, which keeps the command window open after ipconfig has terminated. Or run it from a batch, that calls a sleep or waits for a key being pressed after ipconfig has ended